# Jquery each click ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, click

Been working on an ajax post function which works on it's own - however if I have two instances of the widget then both get fired and display the error message's instead of just the one.

I'm trying the .each() to bind the click but it doesn't want to work.

```
$('.cjd-subscribe-button').each(function() {

    $(this).click(function() {

        var cjd_nonce = $("#cjd-widget #cjd_nonce").val();
        var cjd_email = $('#cjd_email').val();

        $.ajax({
                url: cjdAjax.ajaxurl,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    action: 'cjd_subscribe',
                    nonce: cjd_nonce,
                    email: cjd_email,
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    var status  = $(data).find('response_data').text();
                    var message = $(data).find('supplemental message').text();

                    if(status == 'success') {
                        console.log(message);
                        $(".email-success p.message").text(message);
                        $(".email-success").slideDown();                   
                        $(".email-success").delay(4000).fadeOut();
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log(message);
                        $(".email-error p.message").text(message);
                        $(".email-error").slideDown();     
                        $(".email-error").delay(4000).fadeOut();
                    }
                }
        }); 
    });

});
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="cjd-widget">
        <input type="email" name="cjd_email" id="cjd_email" class="cjd-email-input"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="cjd_nonce" id="cjd_nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'cjd_nonce' ); ?>" />
        <input type="button" class="cjd-subscribe-button" id="cjd-subscribe" value="<?php  _e( 'Subscribe', 'cjd'); ?>" />
        <div class="email-success">
            <p class="message"></p> 
        </div> 
        <div class="email-error">
            <p class="message"></p> 
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: You're using `$(".email-error")` to display the message. Aren't you maybe using the same class for both buttons?

Comment: if I have two versions of the same widget and one gets clicked - both are showing the error or success message. I need them both to work independently of each other.

Comment: Can you share the relevant part of your HTML? It'll be easier to give you an answer.

Comment: HTML part is irrelevant as it works fine singularly. If two of the same HTML elements exist the first when takes president over the lower and as such throws out an error on both html elements, not the one thats clicked. I need to find a way to bind the functionality to each button and only fire off that html block, not both.

Comment: Your `success` does the same thing regardless of which button was clicked. This is why the HTML would be helpful. We don't know what element `.email-error p.message` should belong to.

Comment: email-error p.message belongs to a nested class - like <div class="email-error">
          <p class="message"></p> 
         </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using classes to display the messages. In this way, the messages will be displayed in all elements with that class.

You have to specify which element should contain that message. You can use IDs or not. If you don't want to use IDs, you can access the desired element like that, based on your HTML:

```
$('.cjd-subscribe-button').click(function() {
    var $success = $(this).parent().find('.email-success');
    var $error = $(this).parent().find('.email-error');

    $.ajax({
        success: function(data) {
            var status  = $(data).find('response_data').text();
            var message = $(data).find('supplemental message').text();

            if(status == 'success') {
                console.log(message);
                $success.find('p.message').text(message);
                $success.slideDown();                   
                $success.delay(4000).fadeOut();
            } else {
                console.log(message);
                $error.find('p.message').text(message);
                $error.slideDown();     
                $error.delay(4000).fadeOut();
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

Example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/40ow7ka4/1/)

Give it a try and let me know if it helps!

Comment: Hi Everton - HTML added above as requested.

Comment: My supposed HTML was pretty close :) .. I think my code will help you as it is now.

Comment: The ajax is firing fine - just not showing the error or success (console is though)

Comment: Also if there are two widgets using the same code - why can't I just use an each around the button - surely thats what the function was intended for??

Comment: The event **is** firing once, but you are showing the message twice, that's the problem. I've changed the code and I've made a jsfiddle too. Can you try it again?

Comment: Thats it - works perfectly! thanks for your help. Would have assumed the each would intuitively know which elements I was referring to.

Comment: I'm glad if my answer has clarified you a little bit. :)